# How to create a separate service apart from main application in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, iis, smtp

I have a main application in asp.net.
There I have an option to send mail via SMTP. I want to make a separate mail sending process. That means if I click on SEND MAIL button, the mail should be sent from background without affecting the application (Like **separate service**). I have tried using **separate thread** and its working fine but is there any possibility to make separate mail sending process without affecting the main application. If I close the application (app pool), then also it should send the mail.

Thanks.

Comment: asynchronous operation could be an answer to your problem..

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET app? If so, then **how do you close the application?** You mean, if you reset IIS or your Application Pool suddenly resets itself, both which sounds like a looong shot, are you sure you even need to worry about your app closing?

Comment: Thanks for the reply..This means mail sending via SMTP asynchronous

Comment: thanks David...Yes you are correct....i think there is no need worry about this....But still i want to about the any other way....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement the mail sending logic as a Windows Service and use IPC (for example shared memory via Mutex and MemoryMappedFile) to communicate between your ASP.NET app and the Windows Service.

This has the benefit that the mail sending logic runs as long as the machine is up... if you need persistence (for example to remember unsent messages after a reboot) you can use a DB or the filesystem...

**EDIT - much easier option:**

Setup an SMTP Pickup folder in IIS (it has this option built-in!) and configure your ASP.NET app accordingly (see for example http://www.singular.co.nz/blog/archive/2007/11/28/using-an-smtp-pickup-directory-delivery-method-for-asp-net-development.aspx and http://www.singular.co.nz/blog/archive/2007/12/19/programmatically-setting-the-smtpclient-pickup-directory-location-at-runtime.aspx).

This way your app saves the Mails as *.eml* files into the directory and IIS takes care of the rest (sending/resending/logging etc.). `SmtpClient` has the ability to work with pickup folder already built-in!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a windows service.
Just right click on your solution in solution explorer, pick new project.
In the dialog, choose "Visual c#->Windows->Windows service"

**Edit 1**
If your mails should be sent at certain times you can store the mails with a send-time in a database and have the service poll that database at regular intervals (like once a minute).
If you want to send the mails immediately you can use MSMQ to transfer the mails from the application to the service.

**Edit 2**
As as side note about services. They are not as simple to debug as regular applications since they can not be started from Visual studio. I usually create the actual functions the windows service as a class library. Then I create two projects. First a service that uses the class library that I use in production an final testing. Then I create a console application that uses the same library that I use for development and debugging. That way I can easily build and test my service without the hassle of installing the service and attaching the debugger every time I want to run it in the debugger.